# How to remove a class form from the previous and the next sibling label of the currently active label with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to add a class **civil-active** to the label that is clicked. When the next label is clicked the class is added to it too, naturally. But I want the class **civil-active** to be there only on the clicked label and get it removed from its previous and next sibling if present.

the code that is adding the class is

**js**

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  labels[i].addEventListener("click", addclass);
}

function addclass(event) {
  event.target.classList.add("civil-active");
}
```

Please suggest me what should I do

Comment: In `addClass()` first loop through all the labels and remove the class before adding it to the `event.target`.

Comment: @user1599011 I am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
    at HTMLLabelElement.addclass "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler, find the element having the class and remove it.

```
function addclass(event) {

  // Those lines will remove the class on the element that has it (if there is one)
  let active = document.querySelector(".civil-active")
  if(active){
    active.classList.remove("civil-active");
  }
  event.target.classList.add("civil-active");
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error 

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at HTMLLabelElement.addclass"

Comment: ok I see... I edited.

Comment: thats woring thank you so much